# Как скачать файл с помощью Telethon

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

Мне нужно скачать файл, который я скину другому человеку.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю пример понятен.
Взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660031/how-to-download-a-video-using-telethon/50415043#50415043)

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = XXXXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
phone_number = '+380XXXXXXXXX'
################################################
channel_username = 'vladrunk'
################################################

client = TelegramClient('session_name',
                    api_id,
                    api_hash)

assert client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))

# ---------------------------------------
msgs = client.get_messages(channel_username, limit=100)
for msg in msgs.data:
    if msg.media is not None:
        client.download_media(message=msg)
```